# How to copy one table data to another one between two Azure databases on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I want to copy data from one database table into another database table on the same server in Azure SQL. I have done all of the Azure SQL Cross Database Query' steps that are written here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6445/azure-sql-cross-database-query/but still get the same error whenever I execute a query
'Reference to database and/or server name in 'db name' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.'

[image]

Can you pls help to figure out this?

Comment: Hi @Danial, welcome to stack overflow! If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Danial, may I know why you unmark it?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL database doesn't support across query directly.

We can not use `USE` statements and it not supported. That's why you get the error. We can not run statements like `select * from [other_database].[schema].[table]`.

In Azure SQL database, only [elastic query overview (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview) can achieve cross database query:

- The elastic query feature (in preview) enables you to run a
  Transact-SQL query that spans multiple databases in Azure SQL
  Database. It allows you to perform cross-database queries to access
  remote tables, and to connect Microsoft and third-party tools (Excel,
  Power BI, Tableau, etc.) to query across data tiers with multiple
  databases.

You could follow the tutorial and it may be more complex than on-premise SQL Server:
[Get started with cross-database queries (vertical partitioning) (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical)